# How to add type safety / autocomplete to JSON config files?

Tags: json, typescript, visual-studio-code, jsonschema

Where does `tsconfig.json` get its types from?

[image: tsconfig autocomplete]

I'd like to add such support for config files in libraries I'm building, but I don't know if this is possible or if tsconfig types are just hardcoded into VS Code.

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-schemas-and-settings

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.jsonValidation

Comment: @Alex Thanks, I managed to create a schema based on your links. Do you know how schemas from the JSON Schema Store end up in VS Code, if they ever? Eg. Do new VS Code version bundle schemas or are they downloaded dynamically without upgrading?

Comment: `tsconfig.json` schema doesn't work if you're offline, so they're most likely downloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer by Alex is found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/json#_json-schemas-and-settings